# DI: which method to use

Tags: php, dependency-injection

Here is a simplified version of a simple Data class:

```php
class Data
{

    public function __construct(string $key, string $value, int $ttlInSeconds)
    {
        $this->key          = $key;
        $this->value        = $key;
        $this->ttlInSeconds = $ttlInSeconds;
    }

    protected function getExpiration()
    {
        $dateHelper = new DateHelper();
        return $dateHelper->getCurrentTimestamp() + $this->ttlInSeconds;
    }
}
```

As you can see there is a clear dependency of the DateHelper which is basically a set of date getter and manipulator methods.
Now the mentioned Data class is used widely in the code. Setting the DateHelper via the constructor is of course the first option I'd go for but! If I do that I go by the book, my code will be easy to test but will be harder and uglier to use.
But not just that, whatever class uses this simple Data class will have the very same requirement which means that the DateHelper will appear in the constructor of a lot of other classes as well. What's even uglier.
The other solutions come to my mind are:

1. Using service locator. But it makes testing harder and sometimes confusing
2. Using a setter method to set the DateHelper into the object what only overwrites an already instantiated object
3. Have this dependency in the constructor but with a default value of null. And the constructor would instantiate it if not set

The last 2 solutions are almost the same and I'd prefer the 3. point.
But I wouldn't say that I'm convenient by either of the solutions.
Also an important information is that I don't want to go for autowiring.

I really don't want to start a flamewar about "usability vs testability", just want to know if there are any thumb rules to follow here.

Comment: Can you explain what is wrong with your current code? Why do you require `DateHelper` to be injected? Does it have dependencies of its own? And if so, does `getCurrentTimestamp` require any of those dependencies? Is `getCurrentTimestamp` an nondeterministic function that hinders testability?

Comment: 1) You don't *have* to DI every single helper. If it's self-contained enough and *unlikely to be substituted for any reason*, you don't need to bend over backwards to DI it. 2) The cascading DI to callers of callers of callers is indeed a problem, and typically that's solved by using a DI service, which can figure out the dependency graph and instantiate objects on demand. It's a problem rather separate from whether this particular helper needs to be DI'd or not.

Comment: I think it would be wiser if you would instantiate your classes with factories in the future. Zend Framework 3 makes a great example of it. Basically, your classes would be instantiated by a factory, that has a service locator as parameter. Never inject service locator in a class, that's an antipattern. Make the service locator create your `Data` class.  Check out this link: https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Website_Operation/Service_Manager.html . I think it will be useful.

Comment: Datehelper is self contained yes and usually it can just be instantiated. But when it comes to testing I need to be able to Mock it because the for example the result of the mentioned `getCurrentTimestamp` method is nondeterministic